# Read several bytes, jump over N bytes, and then read several bytes again. how?

Tags: c++

I have a binary file, a.bin, which contains 768 bytes.

And I want put the bytes 16-256, 272-512, 528-768 into

```
char data[720]
```

I did somethin like

```
ifstream a1;
a1.open("a.bin", ios::in|ios::binary)

char tmp[256]
a1.read(tmp,256)
```

And then I did some loop and copy tmp to data[720] in logic. But that looks really stupid. So I want to ask

1. How can I read data to certain position of a char arry ?

   a1.read(tmp[2],2)  // not allowed, how to achieve this?
2. How can I jump over certain day?

   a1.read(tmp16,16); I can use this to jump 16 bytes and neve use tmp16, but it looks ugly.

Comment: have a look at [seekg](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe [ignore](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) is the way to go.

You go.

```
a1.ignore(16);                   // [1]
a1.read(data, 256-16);           // [2] 
a1.ignore(272-256);              // [3]
a1.read(&data[256-16], 512-272); // [4] 
// and so on
```

1. ignore 1st 16 bytes
2. you can go with `data` here, cause it is the address of the 1st byt of the buffer, essentially the same as &data[0]
3. skip next unwanted bytes
4. this will take and pass address of `data[256-16+1]` as the buffer to read into. Plain `data[17]` would just take a value from there, while `&` operator takes its address. I put `256-16` in there cause that is the number of bytes read in previous call, and we want to start reading at the next free space. Numbering from `0` this is it.

Answer (score 8):

For the first question:

```
a1.read(&tmp[2], 2);
```

reads two bytes into `tmp[2]` and `tmp[3]`.

For the second question:

```
a1.ignore(10);
```

skips 10 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

To read to a certain point in an array you need to give it the address

```
a1.read(tmp+2, 2)
```

Or you can do

```
a1.read(&tmp[2], 2) // the & operator is the address of operator
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the position to read in a stream use `seekg`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg