# Reading from binary file to vector.c++

Tags: c++, file, vector, binary

How to read from binary file (bytes, also known as unsigned `char`in **C++**) to vector skipping the first value which is number as unsigned `int 32`, because the first value is also the size of vector?

First value is also the size of the whole file.

Comment: There are a million tutorials on the internet and a million questions on stack overflow dealing with file I/O and storing elements in vectors. Please utilize the search function to find related questions, and then show us some code that you're having trouble with.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I just don't know how to skip first element in binary file.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640001/read-several-bytes-jump-over-n-bytes-and-then-read-several-bytes-again-how

Comment: But you should really be reading the first 4 bytes as a 32 bit uint and using that to reserve space in your vector. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve

Comment: Yes, I use that value, vector.resize(value). But the rest I have to push in  vector, and thank you for the previous comment!

Comment: If you really can't find how to push values into a vector, then edit this question or ask a new question with a [example]. Also see [ask].

Comment: FYI, you should use `uint8_t` to represent bytes.  An `unsigned char` is defined by range.  A 16 bit value can be used for `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
uint32_t data_size = 0;
data_file.read((char *) &data_size, sizeof(data_size));
std::vector<uint8_t> data(data_size);
data_file.read((char *) &data[0], data_size);
```

The above code fragment first reads the size or quantity of the data from the file.
A `std::vector` is created, using the quantity value that was read in.
Finally, the data is read into the vector.

**Edit 1: Memory-mapped files**
You may want to consider opening the data file as a *memory mapped* file.  This is where the Operating System treats the file as memory.  You don't have to store the data in memory nor read it in.  Since memory mapped file APIs vary among operating systems, you'll have to search your Operating System API to find out how to use the feature.